# Preferred books or study to know internal working of .net

Tags: .net, language-design, internal, architecture

I want to know the internal working of .net when we doing any thing at application level. Like if in my project I will create an object of class then what happened in the behind of the scene in .net internal level or when I inherit a base class to a child class then how my child class get all method of base class what exactly happened inside the .net.

It might be a curious question but I want to know the internal depth and working of all. It is most appreciable, If anyone can suggest me a book, reading or a great article in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho, one of the best is ["CLR via C#" By J. Richter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)

Comment: It really doesn't get better than this.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is [Charles Petzold's .Net Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/) free book

In addition to CLR via C#, I also recommend [Advanced .Net Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321578899) and the slightly-dated [Debugging Microsoft .Net 2.0 Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622027) if you really want to dig deep into the internals.